# If you travelled at exactly the speed of light, what would the stars look like behind you?

Tags: physics, relativistic-rocket, alcubierre-drive, vision, ftl

If you were in an [Alcubierre drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) bubble travelling at exactly 1 c, I wonder what it looks like if you looked back, to the direction you come from. If you went faster-than-light you'd obviously see nothing behind you, just pitch black. When travelling at 2 c, I think that the visibility border would be 90 degrees to your sides. But if you went at 1 c, the light beam that reached you from behind is still with you, so does it look like if time was frozen behind you?

I know that when travelling near, at, or above light speed the stars before you would turn blue and the ones behind you red, if still visible. I guess the faster you'd fly the more would the colors shift, until the stars *before* you appeared red, while close to and behind you nothing would be visible.

Comment: I found this: http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/ It sort of answers my question. I can much recommend it.

Comment: I think questions about theoretical toys are probably off-topic (certainly I'd be much more worried about the time machines that pour out of the Alcubierre metric...).  But there have been [at least](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9907019) [two](https://publikationen.uni-tuebingen.de/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10900/48159/pdf/01dissertation.pdf) papers about this I think.

Comment: Further to my previous comment: I've voted to close this.  I think that it's clearly not relevant to space exploration (if Alcubierre 'drives' are possible at all, they're not possible for us).  It may have a home on Physics SE.

Comment: @tfb Why aren't Alcubierre drives possible for you?

Comment: The Alcubierre metric gives you time machines (ie you can travel into your own past).  If that's possible then causality is pretty much dead.  So people tend to assume that metrics which give rise to such things are unphysical.  The Alcubierre metric is almost certainly *directly* unphysical since it violates energy conditions as well, but any similar metric would be considered by many people (including me) to be unphysical.  We may be wrong, and causality may actually be dead.

Comment: @tfb I agree that time travel into the past can't be possible, but how's that related to a bubble flying at relativistic speeds? Afaik there is no time dilation when going at relativistic speeds in an Alcubierre bubble. Or is the bubble itself time travelling?

Comment: Why was my question downvoted and closed, but not other questions in these tags?

Comment: We have a couple of hundred posts on the Physics stack on the Alcubierre drive that you might like to browse. As you can see, such questions have a fairly high probability of getting closed. https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=alcubierre

Comment: @tfb We have had [ten questions tagged Alcubierre-drive](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcubierre-drive) and *this is the first one* that has been closed as off-topic. The community feels they are allowed here we should stick to that or move to make a change in meta and wait for community input. I've listed [plenty of well-received theoretical questions](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1190/12102) so far, we can't suddenly make "theoretical" off topic, and "toys" is your disparagement of what pretty smart people think is more than that.

Comment: @tfb basically I'm saying that we don't re-decide what's on and off-topic over and over again under each question, we first look carefully at precedent and community standards through similar questions via tagging and through meta. Let's try to keep topicality *stable* and make changes after deliberation, not the spontaneous and isolated personal views of a few each time. Community is what makes SE work so well, *we should defer to it* for policy and topicality issues.

Comment: Voting to **re-open as on-topic** because [Alcubierre drive questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcubierre-drive) have never been off-topic just because they are about theoretical faster-than-light propulsion. Let's keep the question open and see what answers can be posted, rather than **insta-prevention of any community member from having an opportunity to post an answer** to an on-topic question.

Comment: @PM2Ring what does that have to do with Space SE? [They're on-topic here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/52032/if-you-travelled-at-exactly-the-speed-of-light-what-would-the-stars-look-like-b#comment171487_52032).

Comment: @Giovanni Just fyi I've asked in meta [Closing “because this should be off topic” when it isn't. How to raise awareness that topicality of a question is not a “shoot from the hip” thing?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1790/12102)

Comment: @uhoh So there is a tag "ftl"? I looked for the tag "faster-than-light" expecting it to be synonymous with "ftl" or vice versa. If the ftl tag exists, please create a synonymous faster-than-light tag.

Comment: @uhoh The main purpose of my previous comment was to point Giovanni to a fairly good collection of info about the Alcubierre drive. I wasn't implying that Alcubierre drive questions should be off topic, either here or on Physics.SE. I was simply mentioning that such questions do have a tendency to get closed on PSE.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for the clarification; I'm not sure how it could be helpful/useful taken in that way in this context, but it's good to hear that it should't be taken to mean anything about asking here.

Comment: Here's the [ArXiV version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5708) of a paper https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.85.064024 about the hazards of radiation from an Alcubierre warp bubble, and here's a brief synopsis on [Universe Today](https://www.universetoday.com/93882/warp-drives-may-come-with-a-killer-downside/). (FWIW, 2 of the authors were regulars on a now-defunct science forum that I used to frequent).

Comment: There's a result, which I think is [this paper by Everett](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.53.7365) which is annoyingly behind a paywall where it's shown that you the Alcubierre metric admits closed timelike curves – time travel into the past in other words.  This is unsurprising I think: it's really the same thing that's true for FTL travel in flat spacetime.

Comment: @uhoh: (a) this discussion should be on meta not here (b) I didn't vote to close it until there were other votes, so I was intentionally waiting to see what people thought, (c) I think questions like this should be on-topic on Physics SE, not least because there has actually been research about this, and finally (d) The Alcubierre metric is *well-known to be equivalent to a time machine*. Are time machines on-topic here?  Because what you are saying is 'yes, they are'.  I'm not going to reply further here: I may be done with Space SE in fact.

Comment: Just sayin' that I can't post on physics, for they require you to be fully registered (with your e mail account confirmed) to ask questions there. But a moderator can feel free to move this question there.

Comment: @tfb I understand; in an earlier comment above I link to a question I'd opened up in meta for this. I won't ping you further here but if you would like to say anything there in meta it will be appreciated. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

You would not see anything, which is the same as appearing as if time stopped.

As you approach 1c, the light has trouble reaching you and appears to drop in wavelength, becoming redder, and eventually invisible as it is stretched out more and more.
Conversely, light reaching you from in front becomes higher frequency, so bluer, eventually turning into high energy gamma rays. 1c is not achieveable by particles with mass, but you can imagine that if a hypothetical ship reached 1c, the light from behind would appear stationary (0 frequency), as if frozen in time, and the light hitting you from the front would have infinite high frequency (none?) and infinite energy (which is why you can't get there).

Incidently, the photons of light which do travel like this experience no time, and from their perspective, the start and endpoints of the journey, and everything in between, occur as one simultaneous, stationary, zero-time moment.